# Internet Explorer changing `<%` and `%>` to HTML comments

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I haven't properly isolating what's causing this, but I'm hoping it'll spark something in someone's mind.

I have a webpage.  In Chrome it renders fine, in IE a chunk of HTML is commented out.

Looking at the DOM IE has commented it out.  Doing some more digging, this is when a `<%` is is in the output and the comment ends where there would be a `%>`.

It's not a HTML encoding issue, that was easy to prove as other characters a rendered correctly and it's fine in Chrome.

I tried to create a test with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IE &lt;% test </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>IE test</h1>

    <div>
        <p>Some &lt;% invisible %&gt; stuff</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this is rendered fine.

The issue must be with a CSS and\or JavaScript library.  We're using the obvious ones:

- jQuery
- jQueryUI
- jQueryValidate

We also have:

- Backbone
- Backbone validation
- Handlebars
- Underscore

So, some interesting points.

1. The commented out text isn't exactly commented out, the first letter is lost.  e.g

   Some <% invisible %> thing

Is rendered as `Some thing`, **but** the comment in the DOM is:

```
<div class="field wide summary">
    some
    <!--nvisible-->
    stuff
</div>
```

2. Despite us having no direct references to Sizzle I see quite a few odd mentions of it.  e.g.:

   `<body style="ZOOM: 1" sizzle-1443121331027="[object Object]">`

Any help would be gratefully appreciated, even it it's just a poke in a probably direction.

*The behaviour is reproducible up to IE 10.*

Comment: Could you possibly host this page somewhere online so we can access it in IE and see what is going on?  Otherwise it's pretty much a guessing game ....

Comment: I'm trying to get something together, but as you can imagine, chiselling an corporate intranet page so it's safe for the public is a gruelling process.

Comment: disable javascript in browser and see what happens

Comment: `<%` is an error in HTML. I'd fix that instead of trying to deal with unexpected behaviour in browsers.

Comment: Also, which IE version are you trying to make this work on? :)

Comment: Erm... Why won't SO print `<body style="ZOOM: 1" sizzle-1443121331027="[object Object]">` in my message?  it just skips over it.

Comment: @Sachin Up to IE 10, IE 10 renders it correctly.

Comment: @Quentin What do you mean by `<%` is an error in HTML?  It's encoded.

Comment: @BanksySan — If it was encoded it would be `&lt;%`.

Comment: I may be missing something...but since when is `<% something %>` [a valid HTML comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/The_Importance_of_Correct_HTML_Commenting)?

Comment: @Quentin Yes, it is.  IE is buggering about with the encoded for of it.  All the other characters in the string are encoded correctly.  In Chrome, *all* the characters are encoded.  (The full string is `<$!|(/-&}{<%+&{£^/_*.%\-@<.:]/]=-=`)

Comment: @menvis It isn't.  It is being replaced *with* `<!--` and `-->` by IE.

Comment: @BanksySan Just to be clear here; you've removed all libraries and determined it is being done by IE?  Because I've been unable to replicate.

Comment: @BanksySan — The *source code* that you are showing us is not properly encoded. IE can't have buggered about with it if it is the source code because you should be copying it from your text editor. Are you saying that that isn't your source code but is something rendered by a browser? `<p>Some <% invisible %> stuff</p>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: In almost every browser, you can right click the page and choose to view the source exactly the way it looked when downloading it. That will also show you any HTML-encoded entities (like `&lt;`) and unencoded ones (like the beginning of a tag, `<`). And yes, having `<% invisible %>` in HTML is an error, whereas `&lt;% invisible %&gt;` is valid.

Comment: Sorry, hasty copy and paste error there.  It is actually `Some &lt;% invisible %&gt; stuff`.

Comment: @Daedalus is that I can repo it on IE but not Chrome or Firefox Developer Edition.

Comment: Might not be relevant, but `<% %>` would be an underscore template.

Comment: @zeroflagL Good spot, I would assume that it would affect all browsers then though... unfortunately, there's no danger of my teasing that out as backbone relies on it.